# Webview loads local html slowly

Tags: android, webview

I have written an application which consists of several local HTML(text and images). I found some related question but that was not the point, this is my problem:

**When I load this files up to the WebView, they don't appear smoothly. It seems there would be some delay before loading the content.**

This is a piece of my code :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ss);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.2.html");
```

How can I stop this happening ?

Comment: Please show your code for activity_ss

Comment: there is just a WebView inside of ScrollView@phil652

Answer (score 0):

I think the following works best:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
}       
else {
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Android 19 has Chromium engine for WebView. I guess it works better with hardware acceleration.

For more info [Android 4.4 KitKat, the browser and the Chrome WebView](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-4-4-kitkat-browser-chrome-webview)

[Hardware Acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) also do's the trick.You can use it in different levels in your application

**Application level**

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

**Activity level**

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<activity ... />
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

**Window level**

```
 getWindow().setFlags(
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

**View level**

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Hope this will work..

Comment: that does not work , i put a textview next to WebView so when the activity is loaded , first textview is appeared and after some milisec WebView appears .